# \emph gets lost in beamer class when used within italic or bold text

Tags: beamer, itemize, bold, italic, emphasis

I use the `beamer`class in Latex. Using `\emph` has worked fine so far.  Now I want to use `\emph`within a bold (`\textbf`) and an italic (`\textit`) sentence. However, the output seems to ignore the emphases. The sentences are in bold and italic font, respectively, but no emphasized words are distinguishable from the rest (or make the difference so marginal that I cannot see it; my eyes are not that good...):

[image: bold and italic text with emphases]

Is the problem about the beamer class here? Or about the fact I use a list (`\itemize`).

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Berlin}      
\usecolortheme{default} 
\usefonttheme{default} 
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
blah blah
\begin{itemize}
\item blah normal without any bold or italics \emph{emph blah!} blah blah
\item \textbf{bold blah blah \emph{emph blah!} blah blah}
\item \textit{italic blah \emph{emph blah!} blah blah}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for any advice!

Comment: Add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. The OT1-fonts don't have a bold italic sans serif.

Comment: that worked for the bold text (which shows the italics now) but not for the italic text, which is still without emph.

Comment: Adding T1 solves just one part of the problem.

Comment: egreg's answer added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` too - and it solves the second problem with the `\emph` doing nothing in an italic context. So his answer is complete. You can accept it, even if you don't understand all the details.

Comment: jap, I just found that out as well -- so I accepted ;-) thanks again for the quick help! It's amazing what a change in three short lines of code can do. I still got so much to learn...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I do

```
\show\emph
```

I get

```
> \emph=macro:
->\beamer@sort {\beamerx@\emph }{1}.
```

and discover that, eventually, the macro `\beamerx@\emph` (where the second backslash is part of the name) expands to

```
> \beamerx@\emph=\long macro:
#1#2->{\only #2{\itshape }#1}.
```

which explains the behavior: you get `\itshape` notwithstanding.

Indeed, we find in `beamerbaseoverlay.sty` the definition

```
\newcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\itshape}#1}}
```

and you can restore the LaTeX behavior of switching to upright when `\emph` is used in slanted context by adding

```
\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\em}#1}}
```

to your preamble.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
\usetheme{Berlin}
\usecolortheme{default}
\usefonttheme{default}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees,shapes}

\renewcommand<>{\emph}[1]{{\only#2{\em}#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
blah blah
\begin{itemize}
\item blah normal without any bold or italics \emph{emph blah!} blah blah
\item \textbf{bold blah blah \emph{emph blah!} blah blah}
\item \textit{italic blah \emph{emph blah!} blah blah}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note. I added `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` as it's necessary for German and solves part of the problem, because in the font family corresponding to Computer Modern T1 there is slanted boldface. I also changed `utf8x` into `utf8` (the former option corresponds to a largely unmaintained and overly complex package).

[image]

On the other hand, you should keep in mind that you're doing a presentation, so such finer details are unlikely to be noticed by the audience or they may be distracting: keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: thanks a lot for the elaborate answer! I'm fairly new to TEX, so especially the in-depth insight on how you got to know the specifications are very helpful! However, me being lazy, I also tried out @Ulrike Fischer's approach and it worked for the bold text -- not the italics, though. :P So I guess I will try to encorporate yours as well :-)

Comment: @PikkuKatja I didn't even realize that T1 is part of the solution, because I added it before even trying, as soon as I saw German involved.

Comment: T1 is always helpful. But since I am not even sure yet do I need the German, I did not have in mind to care about it (yet)... It's solely for sources I might add in the end and I have not decided yet which ones that will be. So there is no German text in the presentation so far, which means I did not see the problematic output yet. But It's nice to have it solved already now -- otherwise I would have probably come back here later with a cry for help at weird Äs and Ös and Üs and ßs.